# SQL advice on importing data into a referenced list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB structure similar to this :

products

> id
>
> itemnumber
>
> description

inventory-count

> id
>
> itemid (reference to products.id)
>
> count

products holds the itemcatalog and inventory count holds a list of records with a quantity on it.

my issue here is i need to import some CSV data to the inventory-count table too, here i will not have the itemid reference, but instead i have the itemnumber.

So to import it and keep the structure i would need to for each record in the CSV, find the id of the itemnumber in products first, and then create a new record in inventory-count with this id.

Im afraid this might get slow ? is there any suggestions if this is the right way of doing it or an advice on a better model ?

Comment: Import your data to a staging table.  Do what you need to do with it there.  Write to your main table from your staging table.

Comment: I want to import csv data into the inventory-count table, here it only has itemnumber and not the ref id to the product so would have to search for it first in products to get the id. If i add records from the userinterface it will add to inventory-count too, but here i add it by the id as reference to the product.